# How to connect to MSK cluster using Plain Java Kafka Client without Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-msk

I need to connect to MSK Cluster from ec2 but using plain java kafka client library and without sprintboot.
I am getting multiple option using sprintboot but i am looking for a code in plain java without sprintboot.

I tried https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-msk-java-app-cdk/tree/main/consumer code and its working fine but i need in plain java without using Springboot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.